# How to use react-leaflet containerPointToLatLng?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to change the position of a dynamically changed Marker, which coordinates I am taking from a json as pixels to degrees. But I am taking the following error:

> containerPointToLatLng is not defined no-undef react-leaflet

I tried to import `containerPointToLatLng` through

```
import {L,containerPointToLatLng } from 'leaflet';
```

But it didn't worked, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`containerPointToLatLng` is a method of [`Map` class](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-conversion-methods), the below example demonstrates how to place a marker if pixel coordinates are given

```
class MapExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 8,
      markerPoint: {
        x: 733,
        y: 62
      }
    };
    this.refMap = React.createRef();

    this.setMarkerPos = marker => {
      const map = this.refMap.current.leafletElement;
      const m = marker.leafletElement;
      const markerLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(this.state.markerPoint);
      m.setLatLng(markerLatLng);
    };
  }


  render() {
    const { lat, lng, zoom } = this.state;
    const position = [lat, lng];
    return (
      <Map  ref={this.refMap}
        center={position} zoom={zoom}
      >
        <TileLayer 
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
        />
        <Marker position={{lat:0,lng:0}} ref={this.setMarkerPos.bind(this)} />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4q9j748w9) for your reference

Comment: Hi Vadim,  i tried to to something like this https://gist.github.com/YannisKalaijakis/9b2fbe5bf78c48f9794637aeb925b5e0 .But i don't really know how to add containerPointToLatLng into my map Arrow Function. Because i am taking longtitude and latitude as pixels but when i try to locate the markers, these are not located to the correct point.

Comment: i tried this,  

 const LeafletMarkers1 = this.state.products.map(marker => (
      // containerPointToLatLng [marker.latitude / 3.83, marker.longitude / 3.45]
      // marker.latitude / 4.95, marker.longitude / 5.15]
      //lat={marker.latlng[0]}
      //lng={marker.latlng[1]}

        <Marker position={[ (marker.latitude / 4.50) , (marker.longitude / 4.63)]} key={`marker_${marker.id}`} icon={myIcon1}> 
but i cant take the right latitude for my markers.